# Firebase authentication provider silently changes from password to google.com

Tags: firebase-authentication

I use firebase authentication for my web app with three providers: email-password, google, or facebook. I have enabled the option "One account per email address".

When a user signs up using email-password (with a gmail address), then later  uses google sign-in, I expect to receive an exception "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential", but I do not. His providerId is changed to *google.com* and he cannot use his password anymore (throws "auth/wrong-password").

Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication has a concept of a preferred provider for certain email addresses. The most common one is that google.com is the preferred provider for `@gmail.com` addresses, but I think they also exist for Facebook and Microsoft accounts.

If an existing account later signs up again from a preferred provider, that provider overwrites the existing user account. There is no way to change this behavior (that I know of).

Also see:

- Github issue [Facebook provider overwritten by Google provider](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1180)
- Mailing list [Firebase Social Authentication Issue with fb and gmail flow](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/ms_NVQem_Cw/m/8g7BFk1IAAAJ)
- [Authentication using Facebook at first and then Google causes an error in Firebase for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947944/authentication-using-facebook-at-first-and-then-google-causes-an-error-in-fireba/37973121#37973121)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The links about *preferred* and *trusted* providers are helping. This notion could be a nice addition to the firebase guides.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `email_verified` to True after the user has signed up, their sign-in provider does not get replaced when they sign in with a non-email-verified sign-in provider.

E.g. using the Python firebase_admin:

```py
from firebase_admin import auth

# Get token from request
authorized_user = auth.verify_id_token(token)
auth.update_user(authorized_user["uid"], email_verified=True)
```

But it's better to verify their email address of course. Only use this if you know they own the email address.

Comment: This is very important. If the users email signup is not verified, it will not be kept once a verified provider sign-in (such as Google) happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm solving it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Just link the "accounts".

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023:

You can now choose if you want to allow 'User account linking'. For example, if you don't allow multiple accounts with the same email address, a user cannot create a new account that signs in using a Google Account with the email address ex@gmail.com if there already is an account that signs in using the email address ex@gmail.com and a password.

If you do allow multiple accounts with the same email address, your app's sign-in flow cannot rely on an email address to identify a user account.

You can find this under settings within Firebase Authentication.

There are some caveats to using this feature, please read about it [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820?authuser=0&hl=en)

[image: Firebase Authentication Settings]