How to check if my user has signed in with my customOAuth using firebase
I have a spotify oAuth2.0 on my application and i have successfully linked it to my firebase using firebase admin sdk createCustomTokens. When i do this the response gotten from firebase about my users has no providerData. Now when my user tries another method of signing in e.g google. Firebase automatically treats both account as one and updates the users details. Once this is done firebase automatically creates a providerData for the user. Now my issue is i cannot tell if my user has used tried to sign in with spotify. How can i update my users details and add providerID: 'spotify.com' as part of the provider data so as to identify that the user has signed in using spotify

It sounds like your project only allows one account per email address (the default behavior) and you're using a gmail address to test this (for which Google is the preferred provider). If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565874/firebase-authentication-provider-silently-changes-from-password-to-google-com

I understand how Firebase updates the user credentials, especially when Gmail accounts are used. So, would you advise that I use something else, like Firestore, to indicate when a user has also signed up with Spotify?

I'm not really sure what it means to sign up with Spotify here. Are they using the same email address they use to sign in to Spotify to sign into your app? Is that a built-in provider from Firebase nowadays?
